# Get path of onSkipInRead Item

Tags: spring-batch

Is there a way to get the location of the failed to be read input file to use it in a `SkipListener`?

Example:
My `SkipListener` moves every file that failed to be processed or written to an error location:

```
@Override
    public void onSkipInWrite(MyFileObject arg0, Throwable arg1) {
        logger.error("onSkipInWrite ");
        logToErrorDirectory(arg0.getPath(), arg1);

    }

@Override
    public void onSkipInProcess(MyFileObject arg0, Throwable arg1) {
        logger.error("onSkipInProcess ");
        logToErrorDirectory(arg0.getPath(), arg1);

    }

@Override
    public void onSkipInRead(Throwable arg1) {
        // WHAT TO DO HERE

    }
```

I need to do the same thing when an Item (`.xml` file to be precise) **fails to be read too.**

My configuration:

```
<bean id="ExportPatentReader"
        class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader"
        scope="step">
        <property name="resources" value="file:SomeFolder/*.xml'</property>
        <property name="delegate" ref="staxPatentReader"></property>
        <property name="strict" value="true"></property>
    </bean>

<bean id="staxPatentReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemReader"
        scope="step">
        <property name="fragmentRootElementName" value="Root" />
        <property name="unmarshaller" ref="patentMarshaller" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="patentMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
        <property name="classesToBeBound">
            <list>
                <value>com.company.MyFileObject</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

In `MyFileObject` I can easily get the resource and move the file but the problem is before that. **A typical case is a malformed xml file which still needs to be moved to the error directory** but because it's still unmarshalled I can not find a way to get it's resource path.

**---------------------UPDATE---------------------**

Following @Michael Minella 's suggestion I used the sorted `Resources[]` and the `MultiResourceItemReader.resourceIndex`to get the failed file. For **commit-interval=1** worked perfectly! But for bigger ci no luck :( .

My adjusted part of Listener:

```
@Override
    public void onSkipInRead(Throwable arg0) {
        logger.error("onSkipInRead ");

        ExecutionContext stepContext = stepExecution.getExecutionContext();
        logger.info("ExecutionContext: " + stepContext.toString());
        logger.info("stepExecution: " + stepExecution.toString());

        Arrays.sort(resources, comparator);

        Resource errorResource = resources[stepContext.getInt("MultiResourceItemReader.resourceIndex")+1];

        // NOT WORKING
        Resource errorResource2 = resources[stepExecution.getReadCount()+1];
        try {
            // INCORRECT PATH FOR CI>1
            logger.info("Path: " + errorResource.getFile().getCanonicalPath());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

private Comparator<Resource> comparator = new Comparator<Resource>() {

        /**
         * Compares resource filenames.
         */
        @Override
        public int compare(Resource r1, Resource r2) {
            return r1.getFilename().compareTo(r2.getFilename());
        }

    };

@Override
public void beforeStep(StepExecution arg0) {
    stepExecution = arg0;
}
```

Probably the problem is when every commit finishes and `ExecutionContext` is updated but couldn't find a workaround. 
For the update thing during logging the printed stepExecution looked like that: `StepExecution: id=6, version=2, name=partitionedStep:partition4, status=STARTED, exitStatus=EXECUTING, readCount=10, filterCount=0, writeCount=10 readSkipCount=2, writeSkipCount=0, processSkipCount=0, commitCount=1, rollbackCount=0, exitDescription=` 
So I was thinking that maybe the correct index can be a combination of `Items per commit + MultiResourceReader.index`

Another thing... I forgot to mention in the beginning that I use a `partitioner` for reading files although not sure if this affects the result.

The more I play with the `SkipListener` the more I think that an easier solution would be to write a custom reader to replace at least `StaxEventReader` :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up on the proposed solution since I couldn't get it to work with commit-interval>1

A dirty solution that solved my problem:

`Custom Reader` to replace the `StaxEventItemReader` ==>

Added logic of `onSkipInRead()` in `read()` of `Custom Reader` ==>

In order to tackle [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17448541/1499705) problem I tinkered `read()` to run only when a new Resource is read by the `MultiResourceItemReader`:

```
    @Override
    public void setResource(Resource arg0) {
        resource = arg0;
        // true for new resource
        ResourceState = true;
    }

    @Override
    public MyFileObject read() throws Exception {
        MyFileObject item = null;
        /*
         * Run only for a new Resource
         */
        if (ResourceState == true) {
            logger.debug("Reading: " + resource.getFileName());

            try {
                // Actual reading
                item = (MyFileObject) unmarshaller.unmarshal(resource.getFile());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("Error while reading: " + resource.getFilename());

                logToErrorDirectory(resource, errorPath, e);
            }

            /*
             * Finished reading, resourceState=false
             */
            ResourceState = false;
        }

        return item;
    }
```

Not really a fan of this solution but solved my problem!

Answer (score 2):

The `MultiResourceItemReader` keeps track of the file it's working on in the `ExecutionContext` via an index.  When the `Resource []` is injected into the reader, we sort the array by file name.  After that, we store the index of the current file in the step's `ExecutionContext` with each update.  I'm thinking you could implement the same logic in your `SkipListener`.  Inject the same resource array into the listener, sort it, and then pull the index out of the `ExecutionContext`.  You can see this in action in the code for the `MultiResourceItemReader` here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/item/file/MultiResourceItemReader.java

Comment: It was a very interested idea and worked perfectly for commit-interval=1 but not for bigger one. I have updated my question to provide some more details